# Formatting Arguments in Soap Clients

Tags: php, asp.net, soap, format, arguments

Still in way over my head. Don't be too mean!

I'm connecting to an `ASP API` from `PHP` through a `SoapClient` and having trouble passing an argument to one of the methods. That said, I receive the failure result and am able to parse them (thanks @AbraCadaver!) successfully, so I'm not barking up the wrong tree - just climbing it wrong! I can also confirm that manually entering in the key on the API page works, so I've got the correct data.

**Based on the following WSDL, am I formatting the security key correctly?**

My PHP:

```
$loginResult = $soapClient->Login($securityKey);
```

Their WSDL:

```
<s:element name="Login">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SecurityKey" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

FWIW, from their API page:

```
Login 
This function authenticates the user.

Parameters (* required):
SecurityKey*:   Security Key
```

Comment: Not much of a PHP dude, so...IINM you need to assign: e.g. `SecurityKey=foo` of `Login`. Hth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, just something I know 0 about. Two things:

1. The `Login()` function requires an array
2. The `SecurityKey` element in the WSDL above needs to assigned a value in that array via a corresponding key.

This worked for me:

```
$loginResult = $soapClient->Login(array('SecurityKey' => $securityKey));
```